# Проблема с подключением базы данных в Yii2

Tags: php, база-данных, веб-программирование, yii2

Здравствуйте!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не могу подключиться к базе данных на хостинге nic.ru в Yii2 Framework. На других хостингах такой проблемы не было, я делаю вполне логичные действия: в файле /config/db.php записываю параметры подключения к БД в виде:

```
<?php

return [
    'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=****.mysql;dbname=****',
    'username' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Перепроверил, данные ввел верные. Это подтвердила даже тех. поддержка хостинга.

Возможно не удается подключиться из-за кодировки. В параметрах подключения я установил `'charset' => 'utf8'`, а в phpmyadmin на сервере указано: сопоставление кодировки соединения `utf8mb4_general_ci` и сменить ее на `utf8_general_ci` не получается. Мне кажется проблема в этом. Если да то как ее решить? Или хотелось бы узнать, в чем еще может быть проблема? При попытке совершить запрос к бд, php выдает следующую ошибку: `Fatal error: Cannot declare self-referencing constant 'PDO::FETCH_ASSOC' in /home/**my_ident**/**my_domen**/docs/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php on line 634`

Comment: `'charset' => 'utf8'` замените на `'charset' => 'utf8mb4'` для использования 4х байтового UTF-8 в базе. Но это не должно влиять на подключение.

Comment: Если используется APC кеш на сервере, попробуйте его выключить и проверить работу скрипта без него.

Comment: изменение utf8 на utf8mb4 действительно не влияет на подключение, а APC вроде как не используется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В моем случая, перейдя в файл requirements.php, я заметил, что не были подключены расширения PDO. В настройках сервера, а именно в настройках расширений php, я выставил галочки рядом с расширениями PDO и все заработало.

Проблема решена.